# JQuery/JS: Retrieving parameter value from function

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, parameter-passing, awesomium

Say I have a function in JS `function playerJob(job){}`

I call this method from C++ using Awesomium, basically saying

```
int currentJob = GameModeState::changeJob(false);
mScreen->executeJavascript("map.playerJob(currentJob);");
```

All that I want you to see is that I give my JS function `playerJob` a value for it's parameter.

---

What I want to do is then use `playerJob` within my JS to find out what value `job` is. I want to set a variable to that value. I don't know how to get that value out of my method without having to enter a parameter. Say I have my method be

```
function playerJob(job) {
    return job;
}
```

And I try to get job by saying:

`var currentJob = playerJob();`

This does not work, probably because I need to put something within the parenthesis.

I know I could use `playerJob` like this:

```
function playerJob(job) {
    someOtherFunction(job);
}
```

But the problem is that I need this `job` variable before I call any regular "functions". I need to use it within a

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $("#div").click(function(e)
   {
```

Which I cannot really "call".

Is there a way using JQuery to get that variable from my `playerJob` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe keeping a global variable is the correct solutution in this case.

```
var currentJob=null;
//var currentJob="Default Job;

function playerJob(job) {
    if (job) currentJob=job;  //    <------- UPDATED
    someOtherFunction(job);
}

$("#div").click(function(e){
   if (currentJob) alert(currentJob);
}
```

Comment: I'm playing around with this. I think it's working, but I'll confirm first.

Comment: currentJob seems to be remaining "null", but that may be a problem with me setting playerJob. Still working~

Comment: currentJob will remain null if you are calling the function without a parameter. See Update

Comment: Your suggestion is effective with what I needed help doing. Thank you.